# Dimensionality Reduction ValueError

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, scikit-learn, pca, dimensionality-reduction

New to this subject. I was trying to use PCA, from sklearn to reduce my data dimensionally. As I dont know another method I am trying to use PCA to guess how much dimensions it should be used.

My data is an ndarray with shape (51, 2928). With the next code I try to fit the data

```py
pca = PCA(n_components='mle', svd_solver='full')
pca.fit(data)
```

But I deal with the following error when trying to fit the data:

> ValueError: n_components='mle' is only supported if n_samples >= n_features

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like a limitation associated with Minka’s MLE method. It demands a significant amount of data to work properly. The error has said there are not enough rows needed to perform the algorithm. The reference paper is available [here](https://vismod.media.mit.edu/tech-reports/TR-514.pdf)

Comment: I tried with less data and it worked...